# How do i convert C# classes into JSON version of string?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, converters

I want to use this string in Postman to test Web API, i know i can do object serialization by using libraries (for example Newtonsoft), but is there any other way we can get just a skeleton of JSON string for c# classes?

Example:

If i have C# class like this:

```
public class RootObject
{    
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

i am expecting output as:

```
{ 
   "ID": , 
   "Name" : ""
}
```

i can edit the values later while testing in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: @warheat1990 -  OP is asking for **online** tools, not a library.

Comment: If the code is in C#, and running in C#, why do you not just use the framework to do the serialization?? Why do you need this done online??

Comment: How do you imagine this should work online? You want to convert an instance of a class into json? How do you imagine copying these values into a browser?

Comment: I would think (JSON not being my strong suit) that this would be challenging.  When JSON is serialized, it takes an instance of an object that has the structure and the data to be serialized.  It'd be like trying to serialize an interface.

Comment: @Tim, i have huge list of C# class's with so many properties in it, I want JSON version of each class to use in Postman for testing, i can write program to serialize and take JSON string from there, but when ever a class changes i have to run the tool again for JSON string, instead it will be very handy if there is any online tool something like this http://json2csharp.com/. Note: Online tool means it just gives you a skeleton of JSON version, later you can add values in Postman.

Comment: @JamesBlond: I don't want to convert instance of class into json. i think the question is not that confusing since i have give an example also.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you are looking for is something like Json.NET: http://james.newtonking.com/json

It allows you to do things like:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small"
//  ]
//}
```

Comment: OP is looking for **online** solutions, not libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Though I'm not sure if he knows what he's asking for. I'll remove the answer when it becomes obvious what he really wants.

Comment: @Tim, i have huge list of C# class's with so many properties in it, I want JSON version of each class to use in Postman for testing, i can write program to serialize and take JSON string from there, but when ever a class changes i have to run the tool again for JSON string, instead it will be very handy if there is any online tool something like this json2csharp.com. Note: Online tool means it just gives you a skeleton of JSON version, later you can add values in Postman

Answer (score 1):

```
//The Following function will Take the Class object as an Argument and return the JSON obect as String, 
    //Please use the following namespace 
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    public string ConvertObjecttoJSON(object clsobj)
    {

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer =
              new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();


        string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(clsobj); 
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        return jsonString;

    }
```